# How to show current location and all annotation pin on map together iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

How will I show all added annotation and current location blue dot together on map visible rect?

That user can see all pins and his current location when map will load without dragging the map initially. Code for ios8 and ios7.0.

I am using MKMapKit of apple.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680649/zooming-mkmapview-to-fit-annotation-pins

Comment: I am using showAnnotation function but it is not rendinering blue dots and when I am sending current location coordinate in showAnnotaion array it is working fine but pin is coming on blue dot and sometimes blue dot is also not see, only ping showing at current location location coordinate. And why Map is showing grid (not able to see street or country geo).?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
 for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) {
    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
    zoomRect = pointRect;
} else {
    zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
 }
}
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar chekc this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912339/ios-mkmapview-showannotationsanimated-with-padding