# UINavigationBar doesn't expand or extend to the device width

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation, uinavigationbar, extending

The navigation bar doesn't seem to scale to different device widths. It just works on my 5s, but in the simulators, it appears as shown below.

I've created a few apps before, and I never faced this problem.
Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong in this project?

[image: Notice the background change between the navigation bar and the view background]

[image: Similarly, for the iPad Air]

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If not you should :)

Comment: I am very much using auto layout. It's the most awesome thing on the planet :)

Comment: Are you using a custom navigation bar added to a view of a navigation controllers bar?

Comment: No, I've added it in the storyboard.

Comment: Interesting decision. Then you probably haven't set the leading and trailing constraints for the bar. But if you embed it in a navigation controller you will get a bar for free:)

Comment: My root view controller is a navigation controller

Comment: As I said. Please describe your constraints in your question. I'm not sure what the context of this controller even is and why you have added a bar to it. I find it's always easier to simply use the navigation controllers bar. Your constraints should look like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27900842/1652402

Comment: I just noticed that I'm using a category that tries to set the navigation bar's height. However, the widget is untouched. If I remove this category, it all works well. The only line in my category is CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,44) inside sizeThatFits:. Why is this causing the width to suffer?

Comment: I can't tell you without any code. But you definitely shouldn't call sizeThatFits on a bar. Again, auto layout solves this

Comment: Just figured that I don't need this category anymore. I had added it to set the height constant across landscape and portrait, but I don't need it so anymore. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had added a category to keep the height of the navigation bar constant across landscape and portrait modes. This was my mistake. Removing it, solved this issue.

FYI, this was the category:

```
#import "UINavigationBar+DiscoverCustomHeight.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (DiscoverCustomHeight)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,44);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```