# iOS topLayoutGuide using a child view controller difference between iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout, childviewcontroller

Basically I'm trying to resolve the same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140530/toplayoutguide-in-child-view-controller) is asking. However, when I am running the app on iOS 8, everything is working as expected: the child view controller is using its own topLayoutGuide but its position values are set properly according to the ones set at the parent. When I am running on iOS 7 though, the child's topLayoutGuide does not match the parent's.

What has been changed in iOS 8 in order for this to work ?

How can the same behaviour be applied to iOS 7 (possibly without using swizzling and other sorcery as the linked question above mentions.)

Comment: you have difference between iOS7 and 8 because you have on "constrain to margins" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28040616