# auto layout leading or trainling -16

Tags: ios, autolayout

If I just drag a View to occupy all the available screen, when I tried to set auto layout leading and trailing space, it is always saying -16, I am thinking shouldn't it be 0 to the left/right edges?

If I set to 0, actually the view will shrink horizontally by 16 for left and 16 for right.

I am a little confused, why there is a 16 difference?

Comment: In iOS 8, Apple added the layoutMargins property on UIView. layoutMargins takes a UIEdgeInsets value that lets you explicitly define the whitespace that your views can use to guide where portions of the interface should be placed. If you don't want any margins, unselect "constraint to margins", and it will work as expected.

Comment: where is the constraint to margins? I searched the Xcode file inspector, not seeing

Comment: Bottom bar of the storyboard which has wAny|hAny, the second icon on that bar.

Comment: found it.  it is in the popover view for auto layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first add UIView in your super View. and set constrain default leading and trailing is -16 as below image.

[image]

deselect on **constrain to margins** it automatically set 0 of leading and trailing as below image. after set you leading and trailing of view.

[image]