# Should I subclass UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

What's the preferred way to use UIPageViewController?

1. Subclass UIPageViewController and also use that object as the datasource for itself?
2. Create a container VC and add a UIPageViewController as its child VC? (having the container VC be the data source)

Pros/Cons to either approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Approach #2 is preferred. If you use #1, you might run into [this layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19140530/1445366). Also, `UIPageViewController` has many `readonly` properties, and using composition instead of inheritance will encourage you to use it in the way in which it was designed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a parent view controller to implement delegation methods.

You can  simply drag an NSObject in the scene browser and set it's class to your datasource/delegate object.

[image]